# Use a CDN to handle UGC uploads

Tags: cdn, uploading

I was on the phone with a sales guy from Akamai and he mentioned that they offer a service that can handle user generated content uploads (videos in our case) to their edge network.

Unfortunately, he passed me onto a partner company that is clueless and I can't seem to find any more information about it.

Can someone point me to a CDN that offers such a product?

Comment: I found this from Limelight Networks which seems somewhat analogous but I am not quite sure: [User Generated Content - Limelight Networks](http://www.limelightnetworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/User_Generated_Content_QSG_04.20.11.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Akamai offers a [Content Control Utility](http://ndn.newsweek.com/media/79/Content_Control_Interfaces.pdf) (with an API) which could be used to alert its crawlers to content on your servers which needs to be populated to edge caching servers.

Presumably the sales guy was either not familiar with some of the technical aspects of his company's offerings or, more likely, he was trying to direct you to a third-party reseller which provided a more accessible interface if you would rather not invest in developing against the API.